# Detect when any ajax calls fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, post

I have a website where users can work on projects and their work gets automatically saved to my database.  Every couple seconds on my site an ajax (post) call occurs (usually in jquery) to check permissions and what not.

With one section of code is there any way so check if **any** of the ajax calls on your page fail.  I don't want to have to go to every individual call and add a block of code to the end.

Basically this is so I can alert the user if they have lost connection or if something is going wrong.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/

Comment: $.post('url').suceess().error() you can write you code in error..and abort() other ajax by geeting there promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **jQuery** event `ajaxError`. It will be triggered whenever an **Ajax** request completes with an error:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function() {
  console.error('Error');
});
```

Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to override the original jquery ajax function.

```
var $_ajax = $.ajax; // reference to original ajax

$.ajax = function(options) {

     if (options.error) {

        // reference to original error callback
        var originalErrorHandler = options.error;

        var errorHandlerContext = options.context ? options.context : $;


        var customErrorHandler = function(xhr, status, error) {

          // notify error to your user here

        };

        // override error callback with custom implementation           
        options.error = customErrorHandler;
    };

     return $_ajax.apply($, arguments);

}
```

Comment: It is well defined: OP wants to be notified from one place, whenever an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   //ajax setup settings
  $.ajaxSetup ({
     cache: false,
     async: false,
     statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert('Page not found!');
        },
        500: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('Server side:  ' + textStatus);
        }
     }
   });
});
```

I hope this may help you